# Error after making asynchronous thread to a method that has RestTemplate in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, resttemplate

So I wanna ask a question. I was making this routing application and I want to do the routing asynchronously. My code looks something like these:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("restTemplateClient")
private RestTemplate restTemplateForClient;

public void routing() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
          connectToSomeUrl(RequestContext.getCurrentContext());
        }
    }
    thread.start();
}
    
public void connectToSomeUrl(RequestContext context){
//Some logic to validated URL and Request Body
    
ResponseBodyDto responseBodyDto =restTemplateForClient.postForEntity(
            String.format(
              "%s/%s",
              userServiceBaseUrl,
              registerUrl
            ),
            requestBodyDto,
            ResponseBodyDto.class
          )
          .getBody();
}
```

After I tried these approach there is an error which states:

```
exception in thread java.lang.illegalstateexception: no thread-bound request found: are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? if you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of dispatcherservlet: in this case, use requestcontextlistener or requestcontextfilter to expose the current request. at org.springframework.web.context.request.requestcontextholder.currentrequestattributes(requestcontextholder.java:131)
```

Can anybody help me out on this? Thanks

Comment: Among other things, it's bad thread management to create and start random ones like this, plus this provides no crowd control. You should use an `Executor` and/or a tool such as resilience4j.

Answer (score 0):

The *static method* `RequestContext.getCurrentContext()` relies on a `ThreadLocal` that's managed by Spring. If you want to execute your query asynchronously (which you should do by using an `Executor` or a library such as resilience4j, not by spinning off random threads ad hoc), you need to completely prepare the request data before dispatching it (see the Command design pattern).

Comment: so how can I get my application to know if it contains some url format without the RequestContext? . Example: /myapps/register